# Is it good idea to use repair tape to block water from constantly dripping?u

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, faucet, taps

My faucet in the shower started to drip. Till the plumber coming to fix it I thought to mitigate a bit by shutting off the pipe.
I bought a tape similar to [repair tape](https://www.tesa.com/en/consumer/tesa-extra-power-extreme-repair.html).
So if I put tape in the faucet (and remove it to turn on the water when I need to) would it cause a problem? Would the fact that these drips are not released but blocked make things worse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a good idea. A better idea would be to put a bucket under the shower head with a rag in it or over the bucket to dampen the sound.

Comment: But what is the difference between blocking with tape and closing the faucet or e.g. those shower faucets that have a stop button to block the water?

Comment: The shower valve  body has "packing" seal(s) around the stem(s). These are not designed to resist pressure that would build up if you plugged the end of the spigot.

Comment: This reminds me of a cartoon I saw as a kid (Bugs Bunny?) in which Bugs was driven mad by a dripping faucet. He tried this and that--nothing worked, then he fully plugged the end of the spigot and the whole faucet expanded to the size of a watermelon and finally exploded.

Comment: Ok I am not doing it. But I would like to understand what is the difference with e.g. a Shower Head Shut-Off Valve or the buttons in the shower head that block water? Could you please explain in laymen's terms? I don't really understand "The shower valve body has "packing" seal(s) around the stem(s)"

Comment: You are correct that a shower head shut-off and shut-off buttons in a hand-held head would also pressurize the stem seals, but these would be used only for short periods of time usually as a means of extreme water saving (e.g., military water saving). It could also be used to avoid having soap washed off one's body as soon as it is applied especially in a small shower enclosure.

Comment: Also I had in mind the old style rubber washer seal to a brass seat. I don't know how the various "cartridge" valves handle pressurization.